# Error while trying to install nvcc in conda

Tags: anaconda, conda, nvcc

I am trying to install nvcc into a conda environment. The output is as follows:

```
(pytorch_build) user@host:~/pytorch_git/pytorch$ conda install -c nvidia nvcc_linux-64
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: path_to_conda/miniconda3/envs/pytorch_build

  added / updated specs:
    - nvcc_linux-64


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  nvcc_linux-64      nvidia/linux-64::nvcc_linux-64-10.1-hf484d3e_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  certifi            conda-forge::certifi-2020.4.5.1-py37h~ --> pkgs/main::certifi-2020.4.5.1-py37_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? 

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'nvidia::nvcc_linux-64-10.1-hf484d3e_0
'.
Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path_to_conda/miniconda3/pkgs/nvcc_linux-64-10.1-hf484d3e_
0/bin/nvcc'
()
```

I checked manually and `'path_to_conda/miniconda3/pkgs/nvcc_linux-64-10.1-hf484d3e_
0/bin/nvcc'` does exist. 
I tried cleaning the conda package cache but that didn't help either. Next thing I'm removing the entire environment and add nvcc to the list of packages added at first. 
Any else what else I might try? Please let me kow if/which additional information is required.

**UPDATE**
I removed the entire environment and now I'm getting

```
File /usr/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so doesn't exist
```

I'm already looking for solutions with this new problem but would appreciate any help.

Comment: _add nvcc to the list of packages added at first._ That's generally worth doing, even if you aren't encountering any issues immediately.